# Dynamic script addition should be ordered?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-script-loading

I'm adding some `<script>` tags dynamically to the head element after page load. I understand the scripts are loaded asynchronously, but can I expect them to be parsed in the order they are added?

I'm seeing the expected behaviour in Firefox, but not in Safari or Chrome. Looking at the document in Chrome developer tools and Firebug, both show the following -

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="A.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="B.js"></script>
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

However looking at the resource loading view, chrome seems to parse whichever is returned first from the server, while firebug always loads them in the order the script tags were added, even when B is returned first from the server.

Should I expect Chrome/Safari to parse the files in the specified order? Using Chrome 5.0.375.29 beta on OS X 10.6.3

EDIT (10/5/10): When I say parse, I mean execute - can see many benefits of aggressive parsing - thx rikh

EDIT (11/5/10): Ok so I put together a test along the lines of that by juandopazo below. However I have added a combination of things, including

1. Adding the script element to the head directly with javascript. (Tests A -> D)
2. Adding the script element to the head using jquery's append() method. (Tests E -> H)
3. 'Loading' the script with jquery's getScript() method. (Tests I -> L)

I also tried all combination of the 'async' and 'defer' attributes on the script tags.

You can access the test here - http://dyn-script-load.appspot.com/, and view source to see how it works.  The loaded scripts simply call the update() function.

The first thing to note, is that only the 1st and 3rd methods above operate in parallel - the 2nd executes requests sequentially.  You can see a graph of this here -

Image 1 - Graph of Request Lifecycle
[Request lifecycle Graph http://dyn-script-load.appspot.com/images/dynScriptGraph.png](http://dyn-script-load.appspot.com/images/dynScriptGraph.png)

It's also interesting that the jquery append() approach also blocks getScript() calls - you can see that none of them execute until all of the append() calls are complete, and then they all run in parallel. Final note on this is that the jQuery append() method apparently removes the script tags from the document head once they have executed. Only the first method leaves the script tags in the document.

**Chrome Results**

The results are that Chrome always executes the first script to return, regardless of the test.  This means all the test 'fail', except the jQuery append() method.

Image 2 - Chrome 5.0.375.29 beta Results
[Chrome Results http://dyn-script-load.appspot.com/images/chromeDynScript.png](http://dyn-script-load.appspot.com/images/chromeDynScript.png)

**Firefox Results**

On firefox, however, it appears that if the first method is used, and async is false (i.e. not set), then the scripts will reliably execute in order.

Image 3 - FF 3.6.3 Results
[FF Results http://dyn-script-load.appspot.com/images/ffDynScript.png](http://dyn-script-load.appspot.com/images/ffDynScript.png)

Note that Safari seems to give varied results in the same manner as Chrome, which makes sense.

Also, I only have a 500ms delay on the slow script, just to keep the start->finish time down.  You may have to refresh a couple of times to see Chrome and Safari fail on everything.

It seems to me that without a method for doing this, we are not taking advantage of the ability to retrieve data in parallel, and there is no reason why we shouldn't (as firefox shows).

Comment: I've raised this as a bug in the chrome issues register - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46109

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but its been a while and we did come up with a solution. What we came up with was to load the javascript concurrently as text contained in a json object, and then used eval() once they were all loaded to execute them in the correct order. Concurrent load plus ordered execution. Depending on your use case you may not need the json. Roughly, here is some code that shows what we did -

```
// 'requests' is an array of url's to javascript resources
var loadCounter = requests.length;
var results = {};

for(var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
   $.getJSON(requests[i], function(result) {
      results[result.id] = result;
      ...
      if(--loadCounter == 0) finish();
   });
}

function finish() {
  // This is not ordered - modify the algorithm to reflect the order you want
  for(var resultId in results) eval(results[resultId].jsString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, they are meant to be **executed** in the order they appear in the document. Some browser might be able to perform some parsing out of order, but they would still have to be executed in the correct order.

Comment: This was my understanding as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot expect that all browsers will defer execution of both scripts until both are loaded (**especially when you are adding them dynamically).

If you want to execute code in `B.js` only after `A.js` is loaded then your best bet is to add an `onload` callback to `A.js` that sets a variable and another one to `B.js` that checks to see if that variable has been set, then it executes the necessary function in `B.js` if it has (and if `A.js` has not loaded, it starts a timer that periodically checks until it has loaded).

Answer (score 0):

The download order and the execution order is not the same thing. In your page, even if B.js is downloaded first, the browser's engine will wait for A.js to continue processing the page.

The scripts are definitely processed, not only in the order they appeared in the document, but also at the place they appeared.

Imagine if it wouldn't be like that, there would be many errors if your little script that uses jQuery is downloaded and processed before the jQuery library.

Also, when you do a "document.write" in a js file, it appears where the script has been declared. You can't access DOM objects that are appearing after the script declaration neither.

This is why there are recommendations to put scripts at the very bottom of the page, to prevent their execution too soon and decrease the "perceived load time" of the page, because the browser's rendering engine is stopped as soon as a script is processed.

Mike

EDIT: if they are added dynamically with javascript, I think they are processed in the order they were added in time.

Comment: Great this is what I was expecting - so if I am seeing the scripts *not* executed in the order that they appear in the document (which is also the order in which they were added in time), then this would be a bug in WebKit?

I've got four things telling me what's going on (1) The actual structure of the DOM showing the scripts in the right order (2) The resource load view in the dev tools showing the second script being received first (3) The console log showing the order the scripts are being added (in time), and (4) the console log showing the second script being executed first

Comment: Maybe at the last line of A.js, put a line to include B.js via a "document.write"?

Comment: The main goal is to load the scripts in parallel, but execute in the order they were added. This works in Firefox, but not in chrome/safari. I can use the 2nd approach in the test (see edit in main post) to guarantee correct execution order in all browsers, but it's not concurrent. I'm thinking that rather than take your suggested approach to get serial loading (and thus execution), I would go with jQuery.append(), as no extra code is needed in the scripts themselves.  That said, I have serial load working right now - I'm looking for a concurrent load solution to improve performance - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could load **b.js** from **a.js** to be 100% sure ... although I'd like the definitive answer to this question myself, especially with sync ajax loading of scripts.

Comment: That definitely works - I'm in the process of moving away from doing that, to get the performance benefits of loading the scripts concurrently :)

Answer (score 0):

I was investigating this while working on a little library that loads modules dynamically like  YUI 3. I created a little test here that loads two scripts that just insert content into divs. One is a common JS file and the other is a PHP file that waits 3 seconds to execute.

http://www.juandopazo.com.ar/tests/asyn-script-test.html

As you can see, scripts are executed when they finish loading, and not in the order in which you append them to the DOM, in every browser.

Comment: I had a look at the DOM structure for the test, and noted a couple of things - firstly the scripts are in the body rather than the head, and the second script is listed first - so if ordering were honoured, you would expect script 2 to execute first - good test though would be good to see the results when the script tags are in order. ta

Comment: Right. Sorry, I forgot to put them in the head. They were in the wrong order because I used insertBefore() instead of appendChild(). I changed it and the result is the same.

You should be looking at writing some sort of a queue. Ask for modules in different files that call methods from a global object. Take a look at how YUI3 works.

The scripts with your code usually looks like:

YUI().use('module1', 'module2', function (Y) {
    //do something
});

And each module starts:

YUI().add('module1', function (Y) {
   // add your stuff to Y
});

Comment: Thanks for this - I haven't got enough reputation to mark up sorry. Just trying to work out why I am seeing firefox behaving as expected in my scenario, but not in yours. Looks like I've probably misread my situation.

Comment: I'm looking at the 'asynch' attribute that you are adding to the script tag.  Reading here - http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#attr-script-async, it seems clear that it will affect when the script is executed, but it's tough to get a clear picture of what to expect in the scenario where scripts are added dynamically. Will do some testing to see what happens with these attributes.